# While loop always true CCS

Tags: c, pic

I'm using CCS compiler and for this piece of code getting a warning that condition is always true. This is a code for PIC16F877, so when the input is 1 , it should break out of loop. Am I missing something here?

```
int read_keypad()
{
   int value=0;
   while(1)
   {
     UpButton=0;                  // In case of bad Input
     DownButton=0;
     RightButton=0;
     LeftButton=0;
     EnterButton=0;

     output_high(sat1); 
     if (input(sut1)) 
     {    
       value=1;
       while(input(sut1));
       break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop condition is always true. That warning does not mean that your loop could not possibly exit, just not through its test condition.

When input(sut1) returns true you are entering a loop that does nothing until input returns false, then you are breaking out of your outer loop and exiting read_keypad()

Comment: oh okay, so it will break out of loop indeed when the input is 1. Thanks.

Comment: If input() returns true, then returns false is will break out of the loop and exit the function.